# SNMP V3 Get and Set in Ruby

Tags: ruby, snmp

I am looking for a solution which will allow me to call get and set SNMP commands for SNMPv3 in Ruby. From what I have found, there only appears to be the [snmplib](http://snmplib.rubyforge.org/), which only supports versions 1 and 2c. Does anyone know of an alternative gem or library that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using JRuby, you could use SNMP4J:

http://www.snmp4j.org/

If you're using MRI and have the net-snmp library installed, this might work (haven't tried it):

https://github.com/mixtli/net-snmp